# Passing a stream object to a function where the stream can be the console or a file

Tags: c#, stream

I want to write a function that accepts a stream argument. Ideally I would like that argument to be the console (if I want the output to go to the screen), or a file (if I want to save the output).

Something like this:

```
void myFunc(<some stream object> strm)
{
   strm.Write("something");
}
```

How do I declare and call the function to get the behavior I am looking for?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `Stream`, consider using `TextWriter`. That way, you can use a `StreamWriter` for writing to files, and `Console.Out` for writing to the console:

```
static void DoStuff(TextWriter output)
{
    output.WriteLine("doing stuff");
}

static void Main()
{
    DoStuff(Console.Out);

    using( var sw = new StreamWriter("file.txt") )
    {
        DoStuff(sw);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, since the question implies Text based data this would be my choice too.

Answer (score 1):

I entirely agree with Mark's answer: a `TextWriter` is *almost certainly* the way to go.

However, if you absolutely *have* to cope with an arbitrary stream, you can use [`Console.OpenStandardOutput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16f09842.aspx) to get a stream to the console. I would *strongly* advise you not to use this unless you really have to though.